# Defining color in block of diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, shading

Can someone help me to define this color with `\pgfdeclareradialshading`

[image]

```
\pgfdeclareradialshading{spherelavander}{\pgfpoint{-0.8cm}{1cm}}%
{rgb(0cm)=(0.6313,0.6196,0.7411);
    rgb(1.5cm)=(0.47,0.41,0.47)}
\definecolor{lavander}{rgb}{0.47,0.41,0.47}
```

Comment: Please provide the code what you tried so far?

Comment: I have edited the post

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bilinear interpolation comes closer than radial shading.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\definecolor{tl1}{RGB}{214,216,220}
\definecolor{o1}{RGB}{86,73,93}
\tikzset{bl1/.style={upper left=tl1,upper right=o1,lower left=o1,lower right=o1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[block_1/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum width=19mm,minimum
    height = 10mm, line width=0.5pt,rounded corners=1pt,draw=gray,drop shadow}]
 \node[block_1,bl1,text=white,font=\sffamily\tiny]{MAPER};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]